# Image will not show / Text will not center vertically

Tags: html, css, fonts

How do I fix this darn problem? I have Googled, read, revised, experimented, begged, pleaded and I still cannot get the darn images to show.

I have the images in a folder named "images" that is in the same folder as the index.html and the styles.css. When I type out the syntax it is automatically taking me through the locations and to the images so I do not think it is an issue of location.

Also, the bleeping text will not center vertically. I have tried so many different things. It just stays up at the top. I am so frustrated. I cannot believe how freaking stupid I am. I have spent so much gosh darn time on this, I am about to just throw my computer away. I am too stupid to figure out how to make an image appear and to vertically center freaking text. I do not understand how I am having so much trouble with super basic stuff. Do not worry folks, I have not bred so my dumb cannot carry on.

The tenth and twelfth grid containers are supposed to be centered horizontally and vertically. Of course, I have failed there too.

I hate myself so much. I am so sorry you all have to put up with me.

Oh, I even tried adding in a font, one the sanctuary would prefer used, and I screwed that up too.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" type="text/css">
    <title>POHP - Sponsee Rack Card</title>        
</head>

<body>

    <div class="sponsees">

        <div class="sponsee">
            <div class="image">
                <img src="/images/Arya_Llama.png" alt="Arya Llama Image">
            </div>
          
            <div class="text">
                <h2>Arya</h2>
                <p>This ‘guard llama’ absolutely loves being in water, and adores celery.</p>
            </div>

        </div>
      
        <div class="sponsee">
            <div class="image">
                <img src="/images/Button_Sheep.png" alt="Button Sheep Image">
            </div>
          
            <div class="text">
                <h2>Button</h2>
                <p>Our friendliest sheep that loves to be cuddled and hugged.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
      
        <div class="sponsee">
            <div class="image">
                <img src="/images/Caspian_Rooster.jpg" alt="Caspian Rooster Image">
            </div>
          
            <div class="text">
                <h2>Caspian</h2>
                <p>If this very handsome rooster thinks you’re up to no good, watch out!</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="sponsee">
            <div class="image">
                <img src="/images/Cedric_Goat.jpg" alt="Cedric Goat Image">
            </div>
          
            <div class="text">
                <h2>Cedric</h2>
                <p>TThis most affectionate of goats will come say hello and inspect anything new.</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="sponsee">
            <div class="image">
                <img src="/images/Clementine_Horse.png" alt="Clementine Horse Image">
            </div>
          
            <div class="text">
                <h2>Clementine</h2>
                <p>Often found in the barn sampling hay bales and always willing to take a treat.</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="sponsee">
            <div class="image">
                <img src="/images/Darius_Goose.jpg" alt="Darius Goose Image">
            </div>
          
            <div class="text">
                <h2>Darius</h2>
                <p>A proud parent who passionately cares for, and protects, his goslings.</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="sponsee">
            <div class="image">
                <img src="/images/Eddy_Pig.png" alt="Eddy Pig Image">
            </div>
          
            <div class="text">
                <h2>Eddy</h2>
                <p>A friendly, inquisitive Kunekune always ready to join you for a snack and tummy rub.</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="sponsee">
            <div class="image">
                <img src="/images/Pixie_Alpaca.jpg" alt="Pixie Alpaca Image">
            </div>
          
            <div class="text">
                <h2>Pixie</h2>
                <p>Has interesting teeth and will let everyone know about nearby dogs, loudly!</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="sponsee">
            <div class="image">
                <img src="/images/Raja_Peacock.png" alt="Rajah Peacock Image">
            </div>
          
            <div class="text">
                <h2>Rajah</h2>
                <p>A stunning peacock who enjoys opera, and if Romeo and Juliet is playing he is close.</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="sponsee">
            <div id="text2" id="centered">
                <h3>PIECE OF HEAVEN PROJECT</h3>
                <h3>www.pohpsanctuary.com</h3>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="sponsee">
            <div class="image">
                <img src="/images/Ruby_Cow.png" alt="Ruby Cow Image">
            </div>
          
            <div class="text">
                <h2>Ruby</h2>
                <p>A large, gentle, archetypal Highland that adores having bread rolls for a treat.</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="sponsee">
            <div id="image2" id="centered">
                <img src="/images/POHP - Logo.png" alt="Piece of Heaven Project Logo">
            </div>
        </div>
    
    </div>

</body>

</html>



    /*
Much Gratitude Eric!
http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
v2.0 | 20110126
License: none (public domain)
*/

*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */

article, aside, details, figcaption, figure,
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
  display: block;
}
body {
  line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
  list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
  quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

/*
Much Gratitude Eric!
http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
v2.0 | 20110126
License: none (public domain)
*/




/* @font-face {
  font-family: "Bakerie Smooth Wide - Regular";
  src: url(/support/font/BakerieSmoothWide-Regular.otf);
} */

html {
  max-width: 816px;
  max-height: 432px;
  background-color: #d7c3ff;
}

body {
  width: 812.4px;
  height: 428.4px;
  margin: 1px;
  border: 0.8px solid #5a2875;
  background-color: #d7c3ff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: 800;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-stretch: narrower;
}

p {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 200;
}

.sponsees {
  width: 810.8px;
  height: 426.8px;
  border: 0.8px solid #5a2875;
  background-color: #d7c3ff;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
}

.sponsee {
  width: 268.663px;
  height: 105.1px;
  border: 0.8px solid #5a2875;
  background-color: #d7c3ff;
  display: flex;
}

.image {
  width: 105.1px;
  height: 105.1px;
  background-color: grey;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: left;
  object-fit: cover;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.text {
  width: 163.563px;
  height: 105.1;
  background-color: #d7c3ff;
  color: #5a2875;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto;
  text-align: center;
}

#centered {
  display: block;
  object-position: center;
}

#image2 {
  width: 268.663px;
  height: 105.1px;
  background-color: grey;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: left;
  object-fit: cover;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#text2 {
  width: 268.663px;
  height: 105.1px;
  background-color: #5a2875;
  color: #d7c3ff;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: hello, did you try to remove the first "/" before your images url ?

Comment: Yes, the relative path to the images folder at the same level as index.html is `images`, not `/images`.

Comment: Same with the font, the relative path is `support/font`, not `/support/font`. I agree, you are pretty stupid.